# Google Maps in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: android, google-maps

When I try to copy in some old layouts I did in Eclipse into IntelliJ Idea, I get a problem with the Google Maps part in the layout with an error that says:-

**com.google.android.maps.MapView is not allowed here**

I've set the Facets to Android 3.0 Google APIs and the AVD manager is using Google APIs (API Version 11). The Java code even recognises the MapActivity.

What am I missing? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Could you post the offending layout?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem using IntelliJ 11 and I solve like this:

I create a layout called "canvasmap.xml" with this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<com.google.android.maps.MapView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="Your Maps API Key goes here"
        />
```

and in my main layout I use like this:

```
...

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <include android:id="@+id/map" layout="@layout/canvasmap" />

</RelativeLayout>

...
```

just in the place where I'd like to show the map. It works fine and stop to show error.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the problem is myself, but have you tried building the project? I spent a while on mine trying to figure out what was wrong, but in the end when I tried to build it, it still worked properly, so it must be something IntelliJ does not recognize with the google api stuff.